# Django debug toolbar showing only fraction of page load time

Tags: django, profiling, django-debug-toolbar

Loading the index page of my django app on a dedicated (but old) server, takes about 5 seconds (estimate).
Loading the index page of my django app on the localhost takes at most few hundred miliseconds.

I have installed django-debug-toolbar on both of the servers:

production: CPU time ~900 ms
localhost: CPU time ~30 ms

The ping to production server takes about 80ms.

Where did the rest of the time go?

Comment: to lookup db+ network for the db?

Comment: DB is sqlite in both cases. Anyway the DB is mostly empty and nobody else accesses the production server but me now.